# How do I write a matrix in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix

when I declare a matrix inside of a function, **Example: int recur(int mat[][], int....)**
Why the compiler return an error, but with an array it works just fine?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: `error: declaration of 'mat' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first`

Comment: Yeah, I know, I don't know why and how to do it correctly

Comment: You'll need to post more code than this for us to suggest a fix. We could suggest `int mat[][5]` but we have no way of knowing if that is the right dimension. Seeing the call site would help.

Comment: @Federico Lombardo The question does not make sense because such a declaration  int mat[][] is invalid independent on where it occurs.

Comment: Ok sorry guys, I don't have the code in hand, I just wanna know if possible, how to declare a matrix if I have to write the dimension by input in a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler needs to know all dimensions except the first in order to compute an offset.  Think of a two-dimensional array as having rows and columns.  `int mat[4][5]` has 4 rows and 5 columns.

In this case, this is what the array conceptually looks like.  Each number is an index into the array where we'd find the corresponding element:

```
 0  1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
```

However, the way it's actually laid out in memory is as a *linear* sequence of 20 elements:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Accessing `mat[2][3]` tells the compiler to locate element 13 here (2nd row, 3rd column, starting from zero).  It does this by multiplying: `2*5 + 3 == 10 + 3 == 13`.  Note that in order to perform this computation, the number of columns must be known.

If you have the hypothetical variable `int mat[][]` and you attempt to index `mat[2][3]` then how is the compiler to perform this computation?  It has no idea how many columns the array has.  It simply *cannot* compute the element's linear offset because it doesn't have enough information to do so.

Note that the first dimension (4) was not used in the example above; the compiler doesn't need to know this dimension since the coefficient is implicitly 1.

This is why all but the first dimension must be known.  The first dimension is the only one with an implied coefficient.

One solution would be to make the function a template:

```
template <int N>
int recur(int mat[][N]) {
    // ...
}
```

When called with a two-dimensional array, the compiler will use this template to instantiate a version of the function with the appropriate value for `N`, which the function body will use as the multiplication coefficient when indexing the array.

Comment: You can simulate multiple dimensions in one dimension, but you still need to know the total size.  The only way to get the size of a dynamic array is to save the size when you allocate memory.  An array name is still just a pointer to the first element.  All this hassle is why they created array and vector classes.

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett Right. It doesn't change what you need to know, it just expresses that same concept in a different way.